# Where is the log file for Xwayland?

Tags: xorg, log, wayland

When I used to run Xorg, I would get my log files for it in the `/var/log` directory.

But with 21.10, it no longer runs Xorg, but Xwayland.

Every now and then I experience a black screen that I would like to debug. I am not sure if it is my monitor flaking out, or my computer. A power cycle of the monitor does not help.

When I log in remotely, to check on the X log, I have no log file for X in `/var/log` and I don't know where Xwayland puts it.

`$ man Xwayland` will not tell me either, where it should be. I deem this to be a bug, btw. Man pages should mention where the log files are.

## UPDATE

Xwayland is just a proxy for legacy clients, and not the actual graphics manager.

**OS**: Ubuntu 21.10

**Kernel**: Linux deca 5.17.3

**GPU**: Intel Alderlake IGP

Answer (score 3):

You can use [journalctl](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs)  to view the logs. Try the following commands.

```
journalctl -b | grep -i 'wayland.*]: '

journalctl | grep -i 'wayland.*]: '
```

Comment: Thanks! Buy damn, that is one big journal. Mine has 687537 lines in it (without the grep.) Does this log never get cleared?

Comment: You can check the size of log folders using `sudo du -h /var/log/` Then you can use the cd command to move inside the folder you want to clear and use  `sudo du -h *` to see the files sizes. Finally you can clear any log file by sending it to the null dev `sudo cat /dev/null > LOG_FILE_NAME`

Comment: @Bram `$ sudo journalctl --vacuum-size=30M` will truncate the archive.

Comment: I think they show up with `journalctl | grep gdm-x-session` as I have confused Xwayland for the server. But Xwayland is just a proxy. Not the actual graphics server.